# Unable to add users

Tags: users, useradd

When I try to `adduser` or `useradd` it says command is "not found".

Some sources suggest adding /usr/sbin to PATH, but it's already there.

Some sources suggest first logging on as root, but `su` returns "user root does not exist".

For background, I'm trying to do stuff with my Asus router, which is running Linux version 2.6.36.4brcmarm (root@asus) (gcc version 4.5.3 (Buildroot 2012.02)

Comment: Try `sudo su -` then `useradd [args]`

Comment: sudo: command not found

Comment: The instructions in the duplicate thread don't work for me, I don't have a `skel` folder. I hope I didn't break anything now that I partially added a user.

Comment: @AtteJuvonen skel just holds default files for new user, like desktop icons and logon scripts. It is not a required step.